# Multi step form with React hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help debugging this. So when I click the button on the first page to go to next page, it just refreshes the page. What could be wrong please? Here's a recreation of the form. https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-spence-q3vtqw

Tried passing the onSubmit as on onClick event. It takes me to the next page alright, but the data aren't in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be occurring because you're nesting `form` elements which results in invalid HTML and thus unpredictable behavior in the submission and handling of the form.

```
  <Box
    position="absolute"
    right={0}
    left={60}
    bg="white"
    zIndex="2"
    w="600px"
    rounded="lg"
    p={6}
    m="40px auto"
    as="form" // <-- REMOVE THIS OUTER FORM 
  >
     {/* Forms by Step... */}
  </Box>
```

Comment: Aww shucks. Cheers @Ben